# issue cgColor switching in iOS 13 dark mode

Tags: ios, swift, calayer, uibezierpath, cgcolor

I'm facing trouble switching colours when change mode in iOS 13.

The problem is when you see the app in recent apps. UIColors will change but cgColor will not change.

It will change effectively when you open the app but just in recent it will not change.

I'm using "traitCollectionDidChange" method as mentioned in following apple's document. 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/supporting_dark_mode_in_your_interface

---

**Please have a look at Video to understand more clearly** 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C-pcVuPMQ9U&feature=youtu.be

---

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var viewColor: UIView!
    let layerColor = CALayer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        setLayer()
        setColors()
    }

    override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
        super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)

        if traitCollection.hasDifferentColorAppearance(comparedTo: previousTraitCollection) {
            setColors()
        }
    }

    func setColors() {
        layerColor.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "layerColor")?.cgColor
    }

    func setLayer() {
        layerColor.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40)
        viewColor.layer.addSublayer(layerColor)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

For cgColor you need to use

```
layerColor.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "layerColor")?.resolvedColor(with: self.traitCollection).cgColor
```

Comment: Appreciate your response but sadly this is not working for me. as you can see in [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C-pcVuPMQ9U&feature=youtu.be)  that I've posted in question. This problem is not if your application is foregrounded, but if your app is in background and you change the mode, open resent view and you can find the color will change which belongs to UIview and UIViewController but color of CALayer changes wrongly.

Answer (score 3):

When you change mode `traitCollectionDidChange` is called

```swift
class YourView: UIView {

  override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
    super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)

    self.layer.shadowColor = yourUIColor.cgColor
  }

}
```

Comment: FWIW, depending on what exactly you are subclassing you might want to add a "super.traitCollectionDidChange(…)" :)

Answer (score 2):

Lower-level classes, like CA Layer and CG Color, don't understand dynamic colors. It's a UIKit concept.

ref: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/214/?time=1415

For UIView,
I spent lots time to figure out; therefore, I resolve the issue with

```
    
    override open func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
        super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)
        guard traitCollection.hasDifferentColorAppearance(comparedTo: previousTraitCollection) else { return }
        customizeUpdateLayers()
    }
    func customizeUpdateLayers() {
        // do sth
    }
```

For NSView, move that code to your view’s updateLayer() method instead...

ref: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/appearance_customization/supporting_dark_mode_in_your_interface#2993898

ref:  [func updateLayer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsview/1483580-updatelayer)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved it by removing the sublayer, recreating it and adding this new one with the desired color. It works both on iOS13 and iOS14.

Answer (score -5):

your all app with one line solution here,

just you put this line in your appDelegate file

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
    window?.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
}
```

**OR** . you can add in info.plist like this

```
<key>UIUserInterfaceStyle</key>
<string>Light</string>
```

Comment: Khushal I'm looking to solve this issue. the answer you suggested is to prevent dark mode support. Which is not applicable for me. Thank you very much for your time but it's not what I want to know.

Comment: CGColor is not supported by this solution, the correct answer is by Jawad